# How do I tell who triggered the before event on a trigger

Tags: apex, trigger

On and after trigger the object.lastmodifiedbyid contains the id of who do it. But the field has not yet been updated on a before trigger.

Is there a way to tell in the before trigger who edited the record that caused the before trigger to fire?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `UserInfo.getUserId()` method. This method will return you id of user, that invoked trigger event ( you can use it for VF and Lightning as well)

> Returns the context user's ID

Comment: When a trigger gets handed multiple records those records are always from the same User?

Comment: yes, as all those records are in same context, and method UserInfo.getUserId() Returns the context user's ID. So it fits your requirenments

Comment: @Ohmicron See [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/144469) as well.